# Keep getting: FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-textinput

I'm trying to update a field for a certain user when they fill out a certain TextInput. When I fill in the form, it updates the field in the Cloud Firestore. However, I keep getting warnings or errors:

A warning I get: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `array` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextInput)`, expected `string`.

The error I also sometimes get: FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a function

I understand that this is probably also an issue with numbers vs Strings, but I tried converting my value to a String and no solution seemed to get rid of the warnings or errors.

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './styles';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


import { firebase, firebaseConfig, db } from '../../firebase/config'
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";


export default function MoreInfo({ navigation }) {
    var bp = useState(0)
    var age = useState(0)
    var monthsPreg = useState(0)

    //to properly save data 
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;


   
    const onSubmitPress = () => {
        db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).update(
            {
                hasOptedIn: true
            }
        )
       navigation.navigate('Home', { user })

    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView
                style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
                <Image
                    style={styles.logo}
                    source={require('../../../assets/icon.png')}
                />

                {<TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder='Blood Pressure'
                    keyboardType={'numeric'}
                    input type = "numeric"
                    value={bp}
                    onChangeText={
                        (text) => {
                        
                            const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).update(
                              
                                {
                                    "bloodPresure": bp
                                }
                                
                            )
                                .then(function () {
                                    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
                                });

                        }}
                    
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                />}
            
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => onSubmitPress()}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Submit Data</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both errors appear to be converging into the issue being that you are not passing the expected values on the `TextInput` and in the `db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).update()` function.

After checking the [Official Documentation for TextInput in React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#value) I saw that there is no property named `input type` described there. I assume this is the root cause of the issue, try removing this property and it will force the value to became a string that can be properly updated to the Firestore Document.

Comment: I removed input type, but it seems to be still causing a problem. Not sure, what other type I would pass into db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).update() however.

Comment: well, the warning message is saying the the `value` of the `TextInput` (which is `bp`) is an array and not a string, try logging this value somehow, maybe that is part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("users").where("passcode", "==", passcode).limit(1).get().then(query => {
                console.log(query);
                const thing = query.docs[0];
                console.log(thing.data());
                let tmp = thing.data();
                tmp.current_game_play = tmp.current_game_play + 1;
                console.log(tmp);
                thing.ref.update(tmp);
            });
```